# STL std::map operator[] when on the right side of assignment

Tags: c++, stl

I am aware that the map dereference `operator[]` is not `const` and can modify the map. However, I was wondering what happens when the operator is on the right side. For instance:

```
std::map<int, int> a;
int b = a[0];
```

Since `a` will not have the `0` entry will this create a new entry in the map with the key `0`?

Comment: Yes it will. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: The sub-expression `a[0]` does not know it is on the right hand side of an assignment. It will do the same thing it does when it is on the left hand side, or as part of any other expression.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding `operator[]`:

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**.

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), emphasis mine.

This is easy to test, too.

```
std::map<int, int> a;
std::cout << a.size(); //0
int b = a[0];
std::cout << a.size(); //1
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/z7PIRx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, map will create a new entry with key 0 and value 0 in your case.

Below is the description of operation [] in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/

> mapped_type& operator[] (const key_type& k);
>
> If k matches the key of an element in the container, the function
>   returns a reference to its mapped value.**If k does not match the key of
>   any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with
>   that key and returns a reference to its mapped value**.

And sometimes it will introduce upexpected behavior if people forget the operator [] will insert a new key-value pair when it doesn't exist in the map. For example, below is a usural mistake.

```
std::map<int,int> my_map;

//check if 100 is in my_map
if ( my_map[100] ) {
    //some code
}
```

I just want to check whether 100 is in my_map or not, but above code will insert a new key-value in my_map. So in this case, I should use find instead of operator [] if I just want to check 100.

```
std::map<int,int> my_map;

//check if 100 is in my_map
if ( my_map.find(100) != my_map.end() ) {
    //some code
}
```